# Ansible install RethinkDB on ubuntu 16

Tags: package, ansible, rethinkdb

I am trying to use ansible [package](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/package_module.html) to install a specific version of [RethinkDB](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/install/ubuntu/) on ubuntu 16.04.

I use :

```
- name: Ensure rethinkDB package repository is present
  apt_repository: repo='deb http://download.rethinkdb.com/apt xenial main' state=present
  tags:
    - rethinkdb

- name: install RethinkDB
  package: name=rethinkdb-2.3.2 state=latest
  tags:
    - rethinkdb
```

However I get the following error:

> TASK [install RethinkDB]
>   ******************************************************* task path: /Users/nha/.../playbook.yml:173 fatal:
>   [machine]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "No
>   package matching 'rethinkdb-2.3.2' is available"}     to retry, use:
>   --limit @ops/ansible/playbook.retry

Even leaving out the version, I get the error:

> TASK [install RethinkDB]
>   ******************************************************* task path: /Users/nha/.../playbook.yml:173 fatal:
>   [machine]: FAILED! => {"cache_update_time": 0, "cache_updated": false,
>   "changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "'/usr/bin/apt-get -y -o
>   \"Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef\" -o
>   \"Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold\"     install 'rethinkdb'' failed:
>   E: There were unauthenticated packages and -y was used without
>   --allow-unauthenticated\n", "stderr": "E: There were unauthenticated packages and -y was used without --allow-unauthenticated\n", "stdout":
>   "Reading package lists...\nBuilding dependency tree...\nReading state
>   information...\nThe following additional packages will be installed:\n
>   libcurl3\nThe following NEW packages will be installed:\n  libcurl3
>   rethinkdb\n0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not
>   upgraded.\nNeed to get 11.2 MB of archives.\nAfter this operation,
>   40.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.\nWARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!\n  rethinkdb\n", "stdout_lines":
>   ["Reading package lists...", "Building dependency tree...", "Reading
>   state information...", "The following additional packages will be
>   installed:", "  libcurl3", "The following NEW packages will be
>   installed:", "  libcurl3 rethinkdb", "0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0
>   to remove and 0 not upgraded.", "Need to get 11.2 MB of archives.",
>   "After this operation, 40.2 MB of additional disk space will be
>   used.", "WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!", " 
>   rethinkdb"]}  to retry, use: --limit @ops/ansible/playbook.retry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first error message states that the RethinkDB apt repo doesn't contain a package for a 2.3.2 version.

The second error is because you haven't yet added the [apt key](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureApt) to trust this repo. RethinkDB's Ubuntu [installation instructions](https://www.rethinkdb.com/docs/install/ubuntu/) also mentions that you will need to add their apt key.

You can easily do this with the [`apt_key`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_key_module.html) module:

```
- name: add rethinkdb apt key
  apt_key: url=https://download.rethinkdb.com/apt/pubkey.gpg
```

As an aside, it doesn't really make much sense to specify a version and then also specify `latest` on the state.